# Kendo Grid MVC helper column AutoGenerate error

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've got a Kendo grid where I want to auto-generate the columns from the data source.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Foo")
    .Columns(columns => columns.AutoGenerate(true)))
```

This works, but I want to set the columns to a fixed width so I'm trying to use this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Foo")
    .Columns(columns => columns.AutoGenerate(action => { action.Width = 150; })))
```

I don't get any intellisense complains, but when I load the page I get a compile error

> CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is
>   not a delegate type

Is this a known issue or am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message is very misleading because the problem is that the `GridColumnBase<T>` (which is the type of your `action`) type's `Width` property type is `string` and you try to assign an `int` to it.

So you need to write:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("Foo")
.Columns(columns => columns.AutoGenerate(action => { action.Width = "150px"; })))
```